# How to validate input is required in jquery SmartWizard when content load from ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, smart-wizard

i have success implemented jquery SmartWizard for validate input type text, but when input text load from ajax the validate is not working.

code to validate:

```
// Toolbar extra buttons
var btnFinish = $('<button></button>').text('Simpan')
.addClass('btn btn-info')
.on('click', function() {
  if( !$(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
    var elmForm = $("#myForm");
    if(elmForm){
      elmForm.validator('validate');
      var elmErr = elmForm.find('.has-error');
      if(elmErr && elmErr.length > 0) {
        alert('Oops we still have error in the form');
        return false;
      } else {
        alert('Great! we are ready to submit form');
        elmForm.submit();
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

How do i validate the input?

Answer (score 0):

i use this code, it work.

```
var btnFinish = $('<button></button>').text('Finish')
                 .addClass('btn btn-finish')
                 .on('click', function(){
  if( !$(this).hasClass('disabled')){
    var elmForm = $("#myForm");
    if(elmForm){
      elmForm.validator('validate');

      var elmErr = elmForm.find('.has-error');
      if(elmErr && elmErr.length >0){
        alert('Oops, sorry');
        return false;
      } else {
        alert('work! ');
        elmForm.submit();
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you please add an explanation for *why* your snippet does the job?

Comment: oh sorry I took it from the smart wizard documentation on the demo. I inspected the brower element to see the code, and i try this code it work